# High iowait despite small amount of write/read

Tags: linux, oracle-11g, iowait

I'm not sure how to interpret this or the next steps, but why is IOWait so high when I have not written/read much from any devices?

Background: I am a developer trying to find why the DB seems to be slow on a particular environment.

`iostat -tm 60 15
Time: 05:17:01 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.43    0.00    2.28   16.50    0.00   78.78
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
cciss/c0d0        2.14         0.00         0.03      70614     859153
cciss/c0d0p1      0.00         0.00         0.00         41          2
cciss/c0d0p2      2.14         0.00         0.03      70572     859151
dm-0              2.51         0.00         0.01      19375     296915
dm-1              1.69         0.00         0.02      38433     548545
dm-2              0.22         0.00         0.00      12764      13689`

`Time: 05:18:01 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.84    0.00    5.21   54.52    0.00   35.43
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
cciss/c0d0        1.78         0.00         0.02          0          1
cciss/c0d0p1      0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
cciss/c0d0p2      1.78         0.00         0.02          0          1
dm-0              2.47         0.00         0.01          0          0
dm-1              1.22         0.00         0.01          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

`Time: 05:19:01 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.71    0.00    5.24   58.33    0.00   30.72
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
cciss/c0d0        1.68         0.00         0.02          0          1
cciss/c0d0p1      0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
cciss/c0d0p2      1.68         0.00         0.02          0          1
dm-0              1.88         0.00         0.01          0          0
dm-1              1.18         0.00         0.01          0          0
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0`

Comment: I'll answer. I know the issue.

Comment: Can you post the OS, distribution and version?

Answer (score 1):

You can run awr reports with the following.  Oracle will tell you what it is waiting on in under "Top 5 Timed Events"

```
-- run awr (timed_statistics=TYPICAL and control_management_pack_access='DIAGNOSTIC+TUNING')
connect / as sysdba
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing high iowait because the system is idle. Basically, the system has nothing to do but wait for I/O, so that's what it does. When there is lots of idle time, high iowait is not a problem.